# How to Implement 'NaturalSort' in jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid, natural-sort

I started my search to implement 'NaturalSort' in jqGrid, I have Javascript code for NaturalSort as below:

```
this.naturalSort = function (a, b) {
    var re = /(^-?[0-9]+(\.?[0-9]*)[df]?e?[0-9]?$|^0x[0-9a-f]+$|[0-9]+)/gi,
        sre = /(^[ ]*|[ ]*$)/g,
        dre = /(^([\w ]+,?[\w ]+)?[\w ]+,?[\w ]+\d+:\d+(:\d+)?[\w ]?|^\d{1,4}[\/\-]\d{1,4}[\/\-]\d{1,4}|^\w+, \w+ \d+, \d{4})/,
        hre = /^0x[0-9a-f]+$/i,
        ore = /^0/,
        i = function (s) { return naturalSort.insensitive && ('' + s).toLowerCase() || '' + s },
    // convert all to strings strip whitespace
        x = i(a).replace(sre, '') || '',
        y = i(b).replace(sre, '') || '',
    // chunk/tokenize
        xN = x.replace(re, '\0$1\0').replace(/\0$/, '').replace(/^\0/, '').split('\0'),
        yN = y.replace(re, '\0$1\0').replace(/\0$/, '').replace(/^\0/, '').split('\0'),
    // numeric, hex or date detection
        xD = parseInt(x.match(hre)) || (xN.length != 1 && x.match(dre) && Date.parse(x)),
        yD = parseInt(y.match(hre)) || xD && y.match(dre) && Date.parse(y) || null,
        oFxNcL, oFyNcL;
    // first try and sort Hex codes or Dates
    if (yD)
        if (xD < yD) return -1;
        else if (xD > yD) return 1;
    // natural sorting through split numeric strings and default strings
    for (var cLoc = 0, numS = Math.max(xN.length, yN.length); cLoc < numS; cLoc++) {
        // find floats not starting with '0', string or 0 if not defined (Clint Priest)
        oFxNcL = !(xN[cLoc] || '').match(ore) && parseFloat(xN[cLoc]) || xN[cLoc] || 0;
        oFyNcL = !(yN[cLoc] || '').match(ore) && parseFloat(yN[cLoc]) || yN[cLoc] || 0;
        // handle numeric vs string comparison - number < string - (Kyle Adams)
        if (isNaN(oFxNcL) !== isNaN(oFyNcL)) { return (isNaN(oFxNcL)) ? 1 : -1; }
        // rely on string comparison if different types - i.e. '02' < 2 != '02' < '2'
        else if (typeof oFxNcL !== typeof oFyNcL) {
            oFxNcL += '';
            oFyNcL += '';
        }
        if (oFxNcL < oFyNcL) return -1;
        if (oFxNcL > oFyNcL) return 1;
    }
    return 0;
};
```

I tried but did not find a way to consume above code via jqGrid. Can anyone guide me how we can achieve 'NaturalSort' by using above code or anyother way.

Any help in this regard will be most appreciated!

Comment: Filed this issue under github repo : https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/issues/430.

Comment: New feature has been added in jquGrid and would be available in future release. Here is the new feature: https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/6131d8a464243d1120278f99a9cdf053246b518f. I am adding answer to resolve this issue and closing this discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Tony** - creator of jqGrid has been added new feature to handle custom sorting here: https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/6131d8a464243d1120278f99a9cdf053246b518f

It would be available in coming releases of jqGrid. Here is following modified code by Tony to handle NaturalSort order:

```
...jqGrid({
...
data: mydata,
...
colModel : [ 
...
{"name": "field1",...,"sortfunc": naturalSort, ...},
...
],
...
});
```

Note that to the sort function you will need to pass 3 paramaters, where the 3 parameters is the sort order 1 for ascending and -1 for descending.
In this case your naturalSort function should have 3 parameters. Below is the modified code from me.

```
/*
 * Natural Sort algorithm for Javascript - Version 0.7 - Released under MIT license
 * Author: Jim Palmer (based on chunking idea from Dave Koelle)
 */
 function naturalSort (a, b, d) {
    if(d===undefined) { d=1; }
    var re = /(^-?[0-9]+(\.?[0-9]*)[df]?e?[0-9]?$|^0x[0-9a-f]+$|[0-9]+)/gi,
        sre = /(^[ ]*|[ ]*$)/g,
        dre = /(^([\w ]+,?[\w ]+)?[\w ]+,?[\w ]+\d+:\d+(:\d+)?[\w ]?|^\d{1,4}[\/\-]\d{1,4}[\/\-]\d{1,4}|^\w+, \w+ \d+, \d{4})/,
        hre = /^0x[0-9a-f]+$/i,
        ore = /^0/,
        i = function(s) { return naturalSort.insensitive && (''+s).toLowerCase() || ''+s },
        // convert all to strings strip whitespace
        x = i(a).replace(sre, '') || '',
        y = i(b).replace(sre, '') || '',
        // chunk/tokenize
        xN = x.replace(re, '\0$1\0').replace(/\0$/,'').replace(/^\0/,'').split('\0'),
        yN = y.replace(re, '\0$1\0').replace(/\0$/,'').replace(/^\0/,'').split('\0'),
        // numeric, hex or date detection
        xD = parseInt(x.match(hre)) || (xN.length != 1 && x.match(dre) && Date.parse(x)),
        yD = parseInt(y.match(hre)) || xD && y.match(dre) && Date.parse(y) || null,
        oFxNcL, oFyNcL;
    // first try and sort Hex codes or Dates
    if (yD)
        if ( xD < yD ) return -d;
        else if ( xD > yD ) return d;
    // natural sorting through split numeric strings and default strings
    for(var cLoc=0, numS=Math.max(xN.length, yN.length); cLoc < numS; cLoc++) {
        // find floats not starting with '0', string or 0 if not defined (Clint Priest)
        oFxNcL = !(xN[cLoc] || '').match(ore) && parseFloat(xN[cLoc]) || xN[cLoc] || 0;
        oFyNcL = !(yN[cLoc] || '').match(ore) && parseFloat(yN[cLoc]) || yN[cLoc] || 0;
        // handle numeric vs string comparison - number < string - (Kyle Adams)
        if (isNaN(oFxNcL) !== isNaN(oFyNcL)) { return (isNaN(oFxNcL)) ? d : -d; }
        // rely on string comparison if different types - i.e. '02' < 2 != '02' < '2'
        else if (typeof oFxNcL !== typeof oFyNcL) {
            oFxNcL += '';
            oFyNcL += '';
        }
        if (oFxNcL < oFyNcL) return -d;
        if (oFxNcL > oFyNcL) return d;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For more details of logged issue, visit this link: https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/issues/430

[image: naturalSort function results]

Comment: New version of jqgrid v4.6.0 is out which contains many bug fixes and features: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:changetwo#jqgrid_4.6.0_changes_and_fixes. Download is available from here: http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6