# How to do natural sort/alpha numeric sort over columns for y-dimension in jqGrid pivot table

Tags: jqgrid, pivot, free-jqgrid, jqpivot

For columns in y-dimension how to do natural sort for alpha numeric column names ?

For example:
consider column names AA1, AA2, AA3, AA10, AA11.
These are listed in order AA1, AA10, AA11, AA2, AA3 in pivot table y-dimension.

Desired order of columns is AA1, AA2, AA3, AA10, AA11

Comment: This is the "natural" alphabetical order. Achieving what you want would require you to write your own sorting method that would be separating string in two, the first part composed of only letters from the second part of numbers and comparing both separately. This implies your strings always follow this pattern. It would become even trickier if pattern changes alternating several times letters and numbers.

Comment: Let us say I wrote this function, how can I configure jqGrid  pivottable to use this while ordering columns in y-dimension?

Comment: There are some interpretation what is natural sort. I suppose that you know exactly what you mean. Some implementations of sort are relatively complex (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21679588/315935) for example). In general you need use `compareVectorsByY` callback to specify it. I can post an example of usage the callback in my answer, but I want mostly show the way of calling custom sorting and don't want to have long discussion what is "natural sort".

Comment: I don't know jqgrid at all but a quck search on "jqgrid custom sorting" returns some valuable resources was it on SO or the rest of the web... You should have a look at that, try by yourself and if you have any issue come back on SO with a new question showing your efforts (ie: bits of code)

Comment: @LaurentS.: The question is about **pivot** grid. There are source data which is array with some properties. Pivot **sorts** and *groups* input data by some subset of properties defined as X-dimension. It build rows of the grid. Then one **sorts** and *groups* input data by another subset of properties defined as Y-dimension. The results build columns of the resulting grid. So one have group of input items for every cell. Finally one calculates aggregation operator over every resulting group of input item for every cell. So the results of "jqgrid custom sorting" is mostly *not what was asked*.

Comment: @LaurentS.: The usage of custom y-dimension in pivot table are needed to have *another (custom) order of columns* in the resulting jqGrid. See [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/jqPivot-in-version-4.9) and [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jqgriddocs#pivot_grid) for more information about jqPivot method of jqGrid.

Comment: @Oleg can you post an example to call compareVectorsByY callback please ? that would help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Free jqGrid 4.9 contains full rewritten version of `jqPivot`. I tried to hold compatibility with the previous version, but it contains many advanced features. I tried to describe there in [wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/jqPivot-in-version-4.9).

Not so many people uses `jqPivot`. So I remind what it do. It gets an *input data* as source and generate new data, which will be input data for jqGrid. Additionally `jqPivot` generates `colModel` based on *input data* and `yDimension` parameter. During analyzing of *input data* `jqPivot` sorts input data by `xDimension` and by `yDimension`. The order or sorting of `xDimension` defines the order of *rows* of resulting grid. The order or sorting of `yDimension` defines the order of *columns* of resulting grid and the total number of resulting columns. The options `compareVectorsByX` and `compareVectorsByY` of  allows to specify callback function which will be used for custom sorting by the whole x or y vector. It's important to understand that sorting function not only specify the the order of *columns*, but it informs `jqPivot` **which vectors should be interpreted as the same**. For example it can interpret the values `12`, `12.0` and `012.00` as the same and specify that `12.0` is larger as `6`.

I describe below some ways which can be used to customize sorting by `xDimension` and `yDimension`.

First of all one can specify `skipSortByX: true` or `skipSortByY: true` parameters. In the case the input data have to be already sorted in the order which you want. The next important options are Boolean options `caseSensitive` (with default value `false`) and `trimByCollect` (default value `true`). `caseSensitive: true` can be used to distinguish input data by case and `trimByCollect: false` can be used to hold trailing spaces in the input data.

Some other important option can be specified in `xDimension` or `yDimension`: `sorttype` and `sortorder`. `sortorder: "desc"` can be used to reverse the order of sorted data. The option `sorttype` can be `"integer"` (or `"int"`) which means to truncate (`Math.floor(Number(inputValue))`) input data during sorting; The values `"number"`, `"currency"` and `"float"` means that the input data should be converted to numbers during sorting (`Number(inputValue)`). Finally one can **don't specify any `sorttype`, but specify `compare` callback function instead**. The `compare` callback is function with two parameters and it should return well known -1, 0 or 1 values.

For example I created [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/pivotGroupingOrder.htm) for [one issue](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/issues/83). One asked my about the following situation. The web site contains login, which identifies the country of the user. One want to set the user's country as the first in the sorting order. [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/pivotGroupingOrder.htm) uses the following `yDimension` parameter:

```js
yDimension: [
    { dataName: "sellyear", sorttype: "integer" },
    { dataName: "sell month",
        compare: function (a, b) {
            if (a === "Germany") { return b !== "Germany" ? -1 : 0; }
            if (b === "Germany") { return 1; }
            if (a > b) { return 1; }
            if (a < b) { return -1; }
            return 0;
        }}
]
```

It sets `"Germany"` first in the sorting order. As the results one sees the results like on the picture below

[image]

You can use the same approach using the code for natural compare from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14865567/how-to-implement-naturalsort-in-jqgrid/21679588#21679588) and you will implements your requirements.

In more advanced cases one can use the options `compareVectorsByX` and `compareVectorsByY`. The requirement was to place specific country only in one specific year on the first place holding the standard order on all other cases. [The corresponding demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/pivotGroupingOrderVector.htm) uses `compareVectorsByY` to implement the requirement. It displays

[image]

and uses the following `compareVectorsByY`:

```js
compareVectorsByY: function (vector1, vector2) {
    var fieldLength = this.fieldLength, iField, compareResult;

    if (fieldLength === 2) {
        if (vector1[0] === "2011" && vector1[1] === "Germany") {
            if (vector2[0] === "2011" && vector2[1] === "Germany") {
                return {
                    index: -1,
                    result: 0
                };
            }
            return {
                index: vector2[0] === "2011" ? 1 : 0,
                result: -1
            };
        }
        // any vector1 is larger as vector2 ("2011", "Germany")
        if (vector2[0] === "2011" && vector2[1] === "Germany") {
            return {
                index: vector2[0] === "2011" ? 1 : 0,
                result: 1
            };
        }
    }

    for (iField = 0; iField < fieldLength; iField++) {
        compareResult = this.fieldCompare[iField](vector1[iField], vector2[iField]);
        if (compareResult !== 0) {
            return {
                index: iField,
                result: compareResult
            };
        }
    }
    return {
        index: -1,
        result: 0
    };
}
```

It's important to mention that `compareVectorsByY` callback function should return **object** with two properties: `index` and `result`. The value of `result` property should be -1, 0 or 1. The value of `index` property should be -1 in case of `result: 0` and be 0-based index of vectors where `vector1` and `vector2` are different.

Comment: Thanks @Oleg for such a detail answer. Given solution worked for me, so accepting the answer.